# what's the difference between these two command in R?(levels of factor variable)

Tags: r

I'm new to R, I was trying to figure out what is the difference between the last two commands?Are they the same?Because the output are exact the same.

```
yesno <- sample(c("yes", "no"),size = 10, replace = TRUE);yesno
> yesno
[1] "yes" "yes" "no"  "yes" "yes" "yes" "no"  "yes" "no"  "yes"

yesnofac <- factor(yesno, levels = c("yes", "no"));yesnofac
[1] yes yes no  yes yes yes no  yes no  yes
Levels: yes no

relevel(yesnofac, ref = "yes")   #Reorder Levels of Factor
[1] yes yes no  yes yes yes no  yes no  yes
Levels: yes no
```

Comment: `relevel` reorders the levels of the `factor` you've created with a reference level as the first level. since your original factor was defined so that "yes" is the first level, `relevel`ing with a `ref = "yes"` does not change the level order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above example, there is no difference as the first level is 'yes'.  But, if we change the order of `levels`, then the `relevel` willl make the 'yes' as the first `level`

```
yesnofac <- factor(yesno, levels = c("no", "yes"))
yesnofac
#[1] yes no  yes yes yes yes yes no  yes yes
# Levels: no yes

relyesnofac <- relevel(yesnofac, ref = "yes")
relyesnofac
#[1] yes no  yes yes yes yes yes no  yes yes
# Levels: yes no'
```

Check the `levels`, it is now different in `order`

```
levels(relyesnofac)
#[1] "yes" "no" 
levels(yesnofac)
#[1] "no"  "yes"
```

Comment: ah now I get it, but I feel a bit confused why we need to change the order of levels?

Comment: @Cecilia It can be useful in some tests, plotting etc.